# 404 page not found just in one page

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ckeditor

I got an error 404 page not found but it only happens in one page to upload files using ckeditor and when I use the host.
when I was using localhost before it's work well, and I use codeigniter.
is that related with htaccess file?
any suggest why that happen just in one page? 
thank you for advice.

this is my htaccess file :

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

this my url who get error :

```
http://www.myurl.com/AdminFolder/class/funcction
```

that was my upload file page, I use ckeditor. but when I want to upload html it's  error 404 page not found but the file not missing.

Comment: What is the URL of the page not working? What is in your .htaccess file?

Comment: that's url who not work .